# .focus() doesn't work on cloned object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope you are all doing well!

So I have a form that contains list of input text in a row. the form can contains as many rows as possible as there is an 'add row' button that allows user to add dynamically

I use clone() to this 'add row' function and it's working perfectly

Next,each input in a row can only be edited if the corresponding checkbox is checked

I have put the code to the fiddle: [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyew4/2/)

Now, when the checkbox is checked, we directly put the focus to the first input (which I defined the input class ='first'), once this input is filled, it directly focuses to the next input. and it's working fine, EXCEPT: if I add new row, the focus function doesn't work anymore.

My focus function is:

```
 $("input").keyup(function (event) {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $(this).next('input').focus();
            if ($(this).next('input[type="text"]').val() == "X") {
                $(this).closest('.me').find('input').focus();

            }
        }
    });
```

Is that supposed to be that way? Or is there anything I need to add to the script?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead of `clone()`

Code

```
 var new_line = $('#content div.2dtme:last').clone(true).append();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2psY/)

### OR

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://jsfiddle.net/nZQ2k/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://jsfiddle.net/nZQ2k/) using delegated-events approach.

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$('form').on('keyup', 'input', function (event) {
    //Your code
});
```

instead of

```
$("input").keyup(function (event) {
    //Your code
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nZQ2k/)